# Listview without an Image list?

Tags: c#, image, list, listview, picturebox

once again i have a problem that i can't quite seem to come up with a solution to. so here it is, I have a ListView displaying the directories of Image files,i want the listview to display these images for these files, the problem is I also need the images to be modified by the program at a per-pixel level so i have this done on a separate thread, so what i want to do is take my already existing PictureBox list of the modified Images and match up the names of the files with the corresponding image. Any ideas on how to do this?

here is what i have so far

```
public static List<PictureBox> ContentItems = new List<PictureBox>();
...
public static string ContentDirectory = "";

    private void FileTree_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
        FileList.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
        ListViewItem item = null;

        foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            item = new ListViewItem(file.Name);
            subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                { new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"), 
                 new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, 
                    file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};

            item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
            FileList.Items.Add(item);
        }

        FileList.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    }
```

Comment: What specific problems are you encountering with what you have tried so far?

Comment: i don't know where to go next, I have the listview setup and i have the images i want eddied and put into a picturebox list, but i do not know how to match up the files with the correct image.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to match your `ListViewItem`s with the images in `ContentItems`, a way to show an image from `ContentItems` as an `ListViewItem` icon, or both? `PictureBox`s don't really work well as `ListViewItem` icons.

Comment: I want to match the files in the listview with the edited images in ContentItems, i can change it to a list of images instead it wouldn't be hard to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Did have to use an image list after all Heres how i got it to work:

```
    void FileTree_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
        FileList.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo nodeDirInfo = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[] subItems;
        ListViewItem item = null;

        ContentImg.Images.Clear();
        int CurrentImg = 0;

        foreach (FileInfo file in nodeDirInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            string fileName = file.Name;
            foreach (PictureBox PB in ContentItems)
            {
                if (fileName == PB.Name)
                {
                    //Get Image
                    ContentImg.Images.Add(PB.Image);

                    item = new ListViewItem(file.Name, CurrentImg);
                    subItems = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[]
                { new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, "File"), 
                 new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, 
                    file.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString())};

                    item.SubItems.AddRange(subItems);
                    FileList.Items.Add(item);
                    CurrentImg += 1;
                }
            }
        }
```